# Find intersection of 1:1 line and lm line

Tags: r, markdown, intercept

I'm evaluating the performance of a numerical deterministic model, and I'm evaluating its predictive performance against observed data. I made a scatter plot of the observed (Vsurface) vs modeled (Vmod) data, fit a lm (the red line), and added a 1:1 line. I want to find the point where these two lines intersect so I can document where the model shifts from over-predicting to under-predicting. Is there an easy way to do this? Here is the code for the lm:

```
lm <- lm(Vmod~Vsurface, data = v)
summary(lm)
Call:
lm(formula = Vmod ~ Vsurface, data = v)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.63267 -0.11995 -0.03618  0.13816  0.60314 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.20666    0.06087   3.395  0.00185 ** 
Vsurface     0.43721    0.06415   6.816 1.05e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2232 on 32 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5921,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5794 
F-statistic: 46.45 on 1 and 32 DF,  p-value: 1.047e-07
```

Here is the plot code:

```
ggplot(data = v, aes(x = Vsurface, y = Vmod)) +
  geom_point(col = "slateblue2") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red") +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)
```

I'm working in R markdown.

Comment: Just solve this analytically. `0.43721*x+0.20666 = x`   so `x = 0.20666/(1-0.43721) = 0.3672062`

Answer (score 0):

Just to explicitly state [G5W's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4752675/g5w) comment - the model is a list and the co-efficients can be extracted like this:

```
lmodel <- lm(Vmod~Vsurface, data = v)
x1 <- lmodel$coefficients[1]/(1-lmodel$coefficients[2])
### x1 is the intersection point
```

Edited step by step:

```
x <- rnorm(100,10,2)
y <- rnorm(100,15,3)

lmodel <- lm(y ~x)
lmodel$coefficients
```

> Intercept = 13.6578378
>   x = 0.1283835

```
x1 <- lmodel$coefficients[1]/(1 - lmodel$coefficients[2])
x1
```

> 15.66955

Comment: When I add this script into my R markdown file and use the print command, I get this:    numeric(0) I tried changing the x1 to x.1 in case that was the issue, but got the same result.

Comment: I edited the answer as it had a typo: "Coefficients" instead of "coefficients". For any object - you can find the structure of the object using str(objectName) at the console line. In this case all of the items under $... can be accessed/subset like you would any list.

Comment: I just tried it again and got the same answer. When I looked at the structure of the x1 object in the console, I got "num(0)". I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I definitely want to figure out how to extract the intersection point like this since I'll be doing a lot of this kind of analysis in my work.

Comment: Since you did not provide your data, I have shown an example with sample data.

Comment: If my data is in a csv with multiple lines (33 lines of unique values, grouped by column with  Vmod and Vsurface as headers), how do I do that? Sometimes the outputs is tens of thousands of unique values for each column, so I'd like to learn how to have the script look to the csv file rather than defining the data manually.

Comment: This is a different question. if my answer works for the question you asked then mark it as accepted. For loading data from csv - search for that question or read a tutorial (https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-data-import-tutorial) on loading data into R.